# Change marker color base on values in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have a simple data and would like to plot it by using python and matplotlib.
There are some "None" values in y values so I want to change the color of the marker when y value is None.
Please help.
Here is my code:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")

x_vals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_vals = [3, 5, "None", 6, "None"]

plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, marker='o', markerfacecolor="y", label="Y-Value")


plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.tight_layout()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: ??? where do you want to place this y=None marker?

Comment: "None" is different than None. None will not be plotted. How can u get a marker?

Comment: How about if I got value is None or "None" then I will set it at a value that I assign for None or "None" and plot it. How can I change the color of its marker?